# Find the gcd of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$f(x)=3x^2+2$,

$g(x)=x^4+5x^2+2x+2$, in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

Find the greatest common divisor $d(x)$ of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

I try to solve, make long division, and find the answer $5x^2+3$ but this answer is wrong.

thank you in advance.

Comment: For this purpose, you can use Euclidean algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: yes I use this algorithm and g(X)= f(x)q(X)+r(X) find the answer but wrong.

Comment: How did you get that answer? Add that to your question.

Comment: Also, please try to format your post with MathJax; you can search for the tutorial on the Meta page or in the help menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also another way to test your calculations without using the Euclidean algorithm. It is easy to factorize both $f$ and $g$ in the finite field $\Bbb F_7$ by just finding a root, namely we have
$$
f(x)=3(x+2)(x+5),\quad g(x)=(x+5)(x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 6).
$$
So the gcd is equal to $x+5$.

The only difficulty is to show that $x^3+2x^2+2x+6$ has no root, and hence is irreducible. But it is a short calculation to try with $x=0,1,\ldots ,6$.

Comment: yes, I will try this way, then try Euclidean algorithm

Comment: Surely you must know the question (and answers) are all dupes (many times over)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this now (even without Euclidean algorithm it is a dupe). I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your first calculation is correct.

$$\underbrace{x^4+5x^2+2x+2}_{g(x)}=\underbrace{(5x^2+3)}_{q(x)}\cdot\underbrace{(3x^2+2)}_{f(x)}+\underbrace{(2x+3)}_{r(x)}.$$

However, think about the case when you are performing the Euclidean algorithm for two integers, say $42$ and $15$:

$$42=2\cdot 15+12.$$

Do you think $2$ is the gcd of $42$ and $15$? Of course it is not (likewise $5x^2+3$ is NOT the gcd of $f$ and $g$!), so we shall continue this calculation:
\begin{align*}
15&=1\cdot 12+3 \\
12&=4\cdot 3+0
\end{align*}
Thus $\gcd(42,15)=3$. Now you can go back to your original calculation to find the gcd.

Comment: yes I understand my mistakes. thank you for explanation and examples.

Comment: 5x^2+3 = (2x+4). q(x) +r(x).  ı dont find which number is divisible 2x+4. that is  how to find q becasuse 5 is not multiple of 2.(x)

Comment: Well first, here you should find $3x^2+2=q(x)\cdot(2x+3)+r(x)$ instead. You cannot mix up quotients and remainders in Euclidean algorithm (See the above, I took $15$ and $12$ in the second step instead of the quotient $2$ from the first step there). As a hint, $2\cdot 5\equiv 3\pmod{7}$.

Comment: yess I got it. thank you.

Comment: ıs gcd  a number different than 0? I see this question but ı dont understand because I fing gcd like ax+b . This is awkward .